# I installed whisper fork from transformers. It works perfectly on huggingface but gives nasty results on my local device

Tags: python-3.x, audio, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers, openai-whisper

[the model](https://huggingface.co/emre/whisper-medium-turkish-2)

```
from transformers import AutoProcessor, WhisperForConditionalGeneration

processor = AutoProcessor.from_pretrained("emre/whisper-medium-turkish-2")
model = WhisperForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained("emre/whisper-medium-turkish-2")

def record():
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        audio = r.listen(source, 4, 4)
    return audio

avodo=record() # Working properly

audio_data = avodo.get_wav_data()
data_s16 = np.frombuffer(audio_data, dtype=np.int16, count=len(audio_data)//2, offset=0)
float_data = data_s16.astype(np.float32, order='C') / 32768.0 
# wavfile.write('tts1.wav', 44100, float_data) || if i write gives a decent sound file

inputs = processor(float_data, return_tensors="pt")
input_features = inputs.input_features

generated_ids = model.generate(inputs=input_features)

transcription = processor.batch_decode(generated_ids, skip_special_tokens=True)
transcription
```

I don't think I did anything wrong, but I'm not sure

a little help would be greatly appreciated

if i made a mistake it should be while converting the audio to float

What I'm wondering is why the result on the local device is different with the huggingface

Comment: ok . 
fixed when using pipeline , I leave it so others can use it